# Remove element from every list in a column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a pretty simple question, but I'm having trouble achieving what I want. 
I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
base
[a,b,c]
[c,d,e]
[a,b,h]
```

I want to remove the second element of every list, so I would get this:

```
base
[a,c]
[c,e]
[a,h]
```

I suppose there's an easy way to do this, but it's not that usual to work with lists in DataFrames, so I'm not finding anything.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: The DataFrame is just one column, which is comprised of lists, all of the same length. I need to remove one element, so the length of the list is the same as the number of columns of the DataFrame it will become.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.base=pd.DataFrame(df.base.values.tolist()).drop(1,1).values.tolist()
df
Out[635]: 
     base
0  [a, c]
1  [c, e]
2  [a, h]
```

Comment: You understood perfectly. I know it's kind of a weird question, but it's because my data was weird. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

## Don't use `list` in series

Pandas series are not designed to hold lists. You lose all functionality and performance with 2 layers of pointers: one with your `object` dtype array, another corresponding to each list within your series.

Since each list has the same number of elements, separate into columns instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'base': [list('abc'), list('cde'), list('abh')]})

res = pd.DataFrame(df['base'].values.tolist()).iloc[:, [0, 2]]

print(res)

   0  2
0  a  c
1  c  e
2  a  h
```

Comment: I want to split them into columns afterwards. The thing is, data came in a bad format and one useless column split into two, so I need to remove that element of the list, so I can then turn it into a DataFrame. Anyways, I think I can work with this code and achieve what I want. Thanks  !

Comment: `data came in a bad format`. It may be worth trying to fix this upstream rather than expensively in Pandas. Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

You could work on the underlying `np.array`:

```
df['base'] = np.stack(df.base.values)[:,[0,2]].tolist()

>>> df
     base
0  [a, c]
1  [c, e]
2  [a, h]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df['base'].apply(lambda x: x.pop(1))`. Note that `pop` acts in place, so you don't need to assign the result to `base` (in fact, if you do so, you'll get the removed element instead of the remaining list).

However, as @jpp says, you should consider using some other data structure, such as a dataframe with multi-index or a three-dimensional numpy array.

And considering your edit, it's probably easier to convert the data to a dataframe with multiple columns, and then delete the extra column, rather than trying to manipulate a column of lists and then turn it into your final dataframe. It may seem simpler to have "only one column", but you're just putting the extra complexity into a separate layer, rather than getting rid of it. Pandas was built around two-dimensional data being represented as columns and rows, not a single column of lists, so you're going out of your way to not use the tools that pandas was built to provide.

Presumably, you had something like this:

```
data=[['a','b','c'],
['c','d','e'],
['a','b','h']]
```

And you did something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'base':data})
```

You should instead do

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df[[0,2]]
```